# bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design, high resolution displays at 300%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, retina-display, bootstrap-material-design

I have a problem with a screen that has 3800x2400 resolution at 300% recommended. I have one screen at 1920x1080 (monitor 1) and the other as mentioned above (monitor 2), I'm working with rems and my code shows up perfect in monitor 1 but gets too big in monitor 2: all the sizes, margins, paddings are the same in px when I inspect the DOM, except that in monitor 2 it shows up too big and has scroll bars.

```
html { 
  font-size: 8px;

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min-width) { 
    font-size: 10px;
  }

}

@screen-sm-min-width = 768px
```

I use rems that calculates for mobile based on 8px, and for a tablet or larger calculates based on 10px.

monitor 1

[image]

monitor 2

[image]

In monitor 2, its too big and it needs a scrollbar. I inspect the DOM and all the sizes are ok in pxs, same as in monitor 1. Why is this showing up like this?

Comment: Does this problem persist across multiple browsers?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with DPI scaling. [Chrome has had issues with this since version 54.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tyzywUJfkQI)

If you're running the Creator's update on Windows 10, you can fix this by going to your web browser's properties, selecting "Compatibility" and checking "Override high DPI scaling behavior".

[image]

Comment: That works, but I need something over de code, or some code to remove in a library because I can't control the settings of the users. I'm using just in case this lib: https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design.

Comment: It looks like the official response (as linked above) has been "this is a developer issue" with no clarification on what devs can do to fix it. I don't know of a non-client-side solution that can be implemented. It's a big problem for anyone running Chrome on multiple monitors with different resolutions.